# How to save the Jenkins console output in a customized path as a text file

Tags: file, jenkins, text, console

We are building a CICD pipeline for a mainframe job ,using Jenkins as a orchestrator. I have total 4 steps in my job. The next step should get execute ,only if the previous step's condition code is zero.
Hence, we have to decided to scan the console output of Jenkins to check the return code.

To perform this,

- want to save the Jenkins console output to a text file in the customized path. can't able to use the Jenkins workspace as such.

So, please let me know is there a way to save the console output to text and do the search in it.

Thanks.

Comment: What's meant by condition code is zero? Are you talking about the exit code of shell script steps? Have you checked returnStatus and returnStdout fields in https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script?

Comment: Hi, I meant about the return code of job step.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this - https://github.com/wso2/testgrid-jenkins-library/blob/dev/vars/WUMUpdateVerifier.groovy#L108-L120 `def result = build(job: jobName, propagate: false).result`